# openlayers javascript library and xhtml periodically moving a marker

Tags: javascript, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am trying to create a geloalization web application so after looking on the different tools I found that openlayers javascript library can be usefull for me to accomplish this project.
but when I start using it I get many problem: 
so I wonder if some one can help by correcting my code or giving me another way to do this task

i have realized this xhtml page to use it to show the marker periodically moving on the map but I can get the aimed  result.

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head>
<title>OpenLayers Demo</title>
<style type="text/css">
html,body,#basicMap {
width: 80%;
height: 80%;
margin: 0;
 }
 </style>
 <script src="OpenLayers.js"></script>
 <script>
var mapnik;
var lat= 32;
var lon=10 ;
var zoom=5;
var map; 
var marker;
var lonLat;
var fromProjection;
var toProjection;  
  function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");
     mapnik   = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
     fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
     toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
    lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon,lat).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
    map.addLayer(mapnik);
    map.setCenter(lonLat,zoom );
    layerMarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
    map.addLayer(layerMarkers);
    var size = new OpenLayers.Size(30,40);
    var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
    var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('icon/jeep.png',size,offset);
    marker =new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat,icon);
    layerMarkers.addMarker(marker);
    window.setInterval("setMarker()",100);
  }
  function setMarker(){
  lon=lon+0.1;
  lat=lat+0.1;
  var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(new     OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
  var newPx = map.getLayerPxFromViewPortPx(map.getPixelFromLonLat(new     OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(map.displayProjection, map.projection)));
  marker.moveTo(newPx);
   }
  </script>
</head>
<body >
<div id="basicMap"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">init();</script>
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I think I post on the wrong forum

Comment: hey stupid any one has any idea ??